# Restrict namespace pollution in C++ Header

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces

In our team we want to Restrict practice of adding "using namespace" in header at global scope as that is not a good practice and often leads to name collision and namespace pollution.

Is there a way in gcc we can restrict this practice of adding using namespace in header at compile time?

I mean to get some kind of warning when the compiler sees at global scope in header "using namespace".

Thanks

Comment: Install a code review process instead. The fact you need a tool hints it's way too easy to add such bad stuff unnoticed.

Comment: As far as I know this is not the role of gcc and it cannot be done with it. You would have better luck with searching for some static analysis tool like cppCheck and implementing custom rule so you can run it before compilation and see all warnings. Good practice would be also to get code review process

Comment: Though I strongly agree with the suggested review process, it's sometimes easier to change coding habits when a tool is constantly throwing hints at you, rather than individuals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `clang-tidy` together with the [google build using namespace](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google-build-using-namespace.html) check, which should complain on these using directives.

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna throw this one out there, as it **is** a very viable alternative in **this** specific case:

In 10 minutes you can likely in any script language of your choice write something that traverses your source tree and scans header files for "using namespace". Run this script automatically on your "nightly build" and fail the build if any such usage is found.

Comment: This is probably less trivial than it seems. What about using namespace in inline functions?

Comment: Sure, there are corner cases, but adapting to them before seeing the need might be premature, looking at the cost (in implementation time) of alternative solutions. Maybe they have a policy of never doing that in inline header functions? If so, this method catches that too.